# wp-admin redirects to home page in my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

After I logging in to my wordpress (via wp-login.php) home page is loading instead of admin page (dashboard). I am using wordpress 3.0. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Questions like this should be sent to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh , thanks for that. I was not aware of it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to get your hands too dirty, this plugin will do it if you enable the Redirection module after installing: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/

Comment: How can I activate this plug-in when am unable to see wp-admin page? Can I manually activate that plug-in ? or I have this problem due to .htaccess ? I am not aware to handle all these

Comment: Are you unable to access the admin dashboard? If so, you have a plugin interfering - rename plugin folder names until you've effectively disabled the one causing that problem. After logging in, you should be trying yoursite.com/wp-admin in your address bar.

Comment: Can you provide some more details that might help us solve it, like what's installed, the environment WordPress is installed in, etc.?

Comment: It is installed in a linux server by 3ix Hosting. www.srivigneshwar.com/blog , this is my website, The theme is still under development , I am sure there is no problem with that theme because it works fine in my localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a bug in WordPress 3.0 with the wonderful Redirection plugin. When you create a new post/page it will somehow add a redirect that makes the home page redirect to the new post/page.
What happens is that it creates a redirect automatically in the Modified posts group.
Tools>>Redirection>>Groups>>Modified posts
Just delete the redirect that has been created to “/” and it should be fine.
This solves the Redirection plugin bug, problem, issue, whatever. This only happens with newly published posts / pages. Hopefully they will fix this awesome WordPress plugin soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the .htaccess file to remove /index.php, you might have to add an exception for wp-login to your .htaccess file

This is an example I've used to stop this rule for some directories and filetypes (? is for GoDaddy).

```
    #index.php to /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|results\.php|images|blog|wp-admin|wp-login|scripts|captcha|styles|css|js|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```